# I have a problem with QTabWidget, how can I make the Tab panel like this?

Tags: qt, pyqt5, qt5, qtabwidget, tabwidget

there was a part of the interface in a CSGO cheat that caught my attention. I tried to see if I could do the same thing, but I couldn't. Even though I did a lot of research, I couldn't reach a conclusion. Can you help me with my problem?
I want to make a TabWidget like in the attached image, with icon on top and text at the bottom.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ksuD.jpg)

I haven't tried anything, I just want to make tabs like in the image